# Проблема с высотой в блоках

Tags: html, css

```css
.news-fullstory-comments {
  max-width: 1210px;
  margin: 20px auto;
 color:#000;
}
.comment-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 922px;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #29cbf6;
  color:#000;
}
.row.comment-descr {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #27c9f8, #58ffb9);
  height: 40px;
}
.comment-text .nick {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 18px;
  font-family: ProximaBold;
  float: left;
}
.comment-text .date {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-family: ProximaRegular;
  float: right;
}
.comment .heart {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  float: right;
}
.comment-text .likes {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16pt;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: ProximaBold;
  float: right;
}
.comment-text .message {
  display: block;
  font-family: ProximaRegular;
  font-size: 14pt;
  width: 903px;
  min-height: 68px;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
.comment-block {
  display: block;
  width: 1092px;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.comment-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.comment-input textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 876px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 2px solid #58ffb9;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  background: transparent;
  font-style: italic;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  resize: none;
}
.comment-ava-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #58ffb9;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -110px;
}
.comment-ava-wrapper img {
  width: 67px;
  height: 67px;
  margin: 7px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.news-header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #3bc8ef, #54fcbd);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22pt;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-fullstory-comments">
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-text">
      <div class="comment-ava-wrapper">
      </div>
      <div class="row comment-descr">
        <span class="nick">12</span>
        <span class="likes">11</span>
        <i class="fa fa-heart heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="date">111111</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="message">
          Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-text">
      <div class="comment-ava-wrapper">
      </div>
      <div class="row comment-descr">
        <span class="nick">1111</span>
        <span class="likes">1126</span>
        <i class="fa fa-heart heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="date">1512</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="message">
          Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс
          Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="news-header">
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Собственно проблема - как сделать так чтобы высота у "`<div class="comment-block">`" менялась от кол-ва текста. Тоесть - чтобы `<div class="news-header">` всегда находился под блоками, внезависимости от их количества (размер текста в блоках может быть разный.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант после каждого comment-block ставить

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

где

```
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Вставил, не работает

Comment: скопировал всю вашу верстку и стили...поместил <div class="clear"></div> над <div class="news-header"> - и теперь он не наползает на блоки...вы наверно не туда вставили...

Comment: упс, действительно. Спасибо!

Comment: незачто. если ответ подошел пометте его как правильный(слева от ответа галочка)

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто, добавь к блоку `overflow:auto;`:

```
.comment-block {
  display: block;
  width: 1092px;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Рекомендую использовать `min-height` с `overflow:auto`, чтобы скролл не появлялся.

Это решение лучше предыдущего во всех смыслах.

Answer (score 2):

добавил стили

```
.comment-block:after,.comment-block:before{
  clear:both;
  content: " ";
  display:table;
}
```

и работает.

```css
.news-fullstory-comments {
  max-width: 1210px;
  margin: 20px auto;
 color:#000;
}
.comment-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 922px;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #29cbf6;
  color:#000;
}
.row.comment-descr {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #27c9f8, #58ffb9);
  height: 40px;
}
.comment-text .nick {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 18px;
  font-family: ProximaBold;
  float: left;
}
.comment-text .date {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-family: ProximaRegular;
  float: right;
}
.comment .heart {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  float: right;
}
.comment-text .likes {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16pt;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: ProximaBold;
  float: right;
}
.comment-text .message {
  display: block;
  font-family: ProximaRegular;
  font-size: 14pt;
  width: 903px;
  min-height: 68px;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
.comment-block {
  display: block;
  width: 1092px;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.comment-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.comment-input textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 876px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 2px solid #58ffb9;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  background: transparent;
  font-style: italic;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  resize: none;
}
.comment-ava-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #58ffb9;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -110px;
}
.comment-ava-wrapper img {
  width: 67px;
  height: 67px;
  margin: 7px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.news-header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #3bc8ef, #54fcbd);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22pt;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.comment-block:after,.comment-block:before{
  clear:both;
  content: " ";
  display:table;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-fullstory-comments">
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-text">
      <div class="comment-ava-wrapper">
      </div>
      <div class="row comment-descr">
        <span class="nick">12</span>
        <span class="likes">11</span>
        <i class="fa fa-heart heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="date">111111</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="message">
          Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-text">
      <div class="comment-ava-wrapper">
      </div>
      <div class="row comment-descr">
        <span class="nick">1111</span>
        <span class="likes">1126</span>
        <i class="fa fa-heart heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="date">1512</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="message">
          Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс
          Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс Тееектстстстс
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="news-header">
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```